# Manage apt-get based dependency's on Docker

Tags: docker, dependencies, apt

We have a large code based on c++ in my company and we are trying to move to a microservice infrastructure based on docker.

We have a couple of library in house that help us with things like helper functions and utility that we regularly use in our code. Our idea was to create a base image for developers with this library's already installed and make it available to use it as our "base" image. This will give us the benefit of all our software always using the latest version of our own library's.

My questions is related to the cache system of Docker in relation with CI and external dependencys. Lets say we have a Docker file like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install External dependencys
RUN apt update && apt install -y\
boost-libs \
etc...

# Copy our software
...
# Build it
...
# Install it
...
```

If our code changes we can trigger the CI and docker will understand that it can use the cached image that was created before up to the point were it copy's our software. What happens if one of our external dependency's offers a newer version? Will the cached be automatically be invalidated? How can we trigger a CI build in case any of our packages receives a new version?

In essence how do we make sure we are always using the latest packages available for our external dependency's?

Please keep in mind the above Dockerfile is just an example to illustrate we are trying to use other tricks in the playbook such us using a lighter base image (not Ubuntu) and multistage builds to avoid dev-packages in our production containers.

Comment: No, the cached intermediate layers won't be automatically invalidated. You'd need to explicitly rebuild from the start on occasion to see updates to the container's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Docker's caching algorithm is fairly simple. It looks at the previous state of the image build, and the string of the command you are running. If you are performing a `COPY` or `ADD`, it also looks at a hash of those files being copied. If a previous build is found on the server with the same previous state and command being run, it will reuse the cache.

That means an external change, e.g. pulling packages from an external repository, will not be detected and the cache will be reused instead of rerunning that line. There are two solutions that I've seen to this:

Option 1: Change your command by adding versions to the dependencies. When one of those dependencies changes, you'll need to update your build. This is added work, but also guarantees that you only pull in the versions that you are ready for. That would look like (fixing boost-libs to a 1.5 version number):

```
# Install External dependencys
RUN apt update && apt install -y\
boost-libs=1.5 \
etc...
```

Option 2: change a build arg. These are injected as environment variables into the `RUN` commands and docker sees a change in the environment as a different command to run. That would look like:

```
# Install External dependencys
ARG UNIQUE_VAR
RUN apt update && apt install -y\
boost-libs \
etc...
```

And then you could build the above with the following to trigger the cache to be recreated daily on that line:

```
docker build --build-arg "UNIQUE_VAR=$(date +%Y%m%d)" ...
```

Note, there's also the option to build without the cache any time you wish with:

```
docker build --no-cache ...
```

This would cause the cache to be ignored for all steps (except the from line).